# Variable Substitution in non-package deploy step

Tags: octopus-deploy

I know that I can add variable substitution during package deployment, but I have a slightly different scenario. What I need to do is:

1. Deploy my package to the Octopus server (I have a tentacle on the server)
2. Substitute variables based on role/environment
3. Run a script against some files from that package (an encryption process)
4. Re-package the files and use that as an artifact for further steps in the process.

My question is - I need to substitute variables in the files that are in the package (step 2 above) - but they need to be specific to a role in the environment that they will ultimately be targeting, and not the octopus server environment.

Note that the unpacking and encryption must be done prior to further deployment so cannot occur on the target machine.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Can you use a separate machine solely for the encryption process? Why does the artefact need to be encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB method to do this. Your going to have to cut a corner somewhere. I would personally:

1. add another environment called unencrypted prod;
2. scope your variables to both unencrypted prod and regular prod;
3. Add an encryption process step, and have it run only in the unencrypted prod environment.